# UITableViewCell not expanding to fit items fully in content view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I am trying to layout a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIImageView` and `UILabel`.

I have configured my table view with

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

I am adding my views to the table view content view. The label is being cut off however, it is a single line label.

[image: cutoffcell]

```
import UIKit

final class FeedImageItem: BaseFeedItemCell {

  var onRetry: (() -> Void)?

  private(set) var itemImageView = configure(UIImageView(frame: .zero), using: {
    $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  })

  private(set) var publishedAtLabel = configure(UILabel(frame: .zero), using: {
    $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  })

  private(set) var itemTitleLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)

  private(set) var retryButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("reload", for: .normal)
    return button
  }()

  override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    configureBindings()
    configureUI()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
  }
}

private extension FeedImageItem {
  @objc func retryButtonTapped() {
    onRetry?()
  }

  func configureBindings() {
    retryButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(retryButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  func configureUI() {

    [itemImageView, publishedAtLabel].forEach(contentView.addSubview(_:))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      itemImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
      itemImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
      itemImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
      itemImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 184),

      publishedAtLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
      publishedAtLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
      publishedAtLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
      publishedAtLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
    ])

  }
}
```

How can I add items to my content view and have the cell expand with respect to the auto layout anchors I have added?

If I add my items to the view directly, I don't have this issue, but I was under the impression I should be adding to the content view.

My content view looks like the following:

```swift
open class BaseFeedItemCell: UITableViewCell {

  override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    configureUI()
  }

  required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
  }

  open override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: .init(top: 8, left: 12, bottom: 8, right: 12))

    contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    contentView.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 0, height: 4)
    contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.18, green: 0.18, blue: 0.18, alpha: 0.16).cgColor
    contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1

    let shadowFrame = contentView.layer.bounds
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).cgPath
    contentView.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath

    contentView.clipsToBounds = true
  }
}

private extension BaseFeedItemCell {
  func configureUI() {
    backgroundColor = .clear
  }
}
```

By setting a height on my label - `publishedAtLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 44)`

I get auto layout issues also.

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003671220 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fee33523000]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fee335bd2b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003671310 UIImageView:0x7fee33523000.height == 184   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003671360 V:[UIImageView:0x7fee33523000]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fee335bc100'Published 16 May 2020']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003671400 UILabel:0x7fee335bc100'Published 16 May 2020'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fee335bd2b0.bottom - 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036714a0 UILabel:0x7fee335bc100'Published 16 May 2020'.height >= 44   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000366df90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fee335bd2b0.height == 228   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036714a0 UILabel:0x7fee335bc100'Published 16 May 2020'.height >= 44   (active)>
```

Comment: Where and how is contentView setup?

Comment: you should also set a height value for your label.       `publishedAtLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: yourValue)`

Comment: @Frankenstein I have added my content view also

Comment: @Mat this seems to produce auto layout issues, I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are adding and constraining your label to the `contentView`. But, the `contentView` behaviour is handled by `UIKit`. Each time you do this you need to be aware of what's going on exactly with the `contentView` and what it's used for. Here's the documentation link to [contentView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview). From your code, all I could gather is that the `contentView` constraints needs to be set to the `UITableViewCell`. Don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` and since it's already a subview you don't have to add it again. In my opinion, it's better to build out a custom contentView and constraint all the sides to the `UITableViewCell`. Hope this helps you.